# Spring multipart file upload size

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, multipart

My application has following properties set

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size = 10MB
```

and

```
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size  = 10MB
```

But instead of throwing the Springs default exception below

```
{ "message": "Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (12780451) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)", "type": "MultipartException" }
```

I would like to throw `CustomException` with message like `FILE_SIZE_TOO_BIG`. Is this possible?
Can I use `@ControllerAdvice` for this ?

Comment: Why do you want to use `@ControllerAdvice`?

Comment: I want to throw CustomException with custom message. I am ok with any other suggestions. Maybe I am confused about what @ControllerAdvice does.

Comment: Why can't you catch the exception in the upload code block and throw the custom one upstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're a lot of ways to handle exceptions in Spring application. See [exception handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) topic. I think `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler` taken from the provided article will fit your requirements. Try this handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)
    @ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
    public void handleMultipart(MultipartException exception) {
        // to do
    }
}
```

If you get this class picked up by component scan, it should handle `MultipartExceptions` thrown from any controller.

Comment: MultipartException is not necessary caused by a payload being too large.
For this case there is `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` which is specific and extends MultipartException